# ImportError: No module named _mysql

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-python

I'm trying to use the Python module MySQL-python to connect to an external MySQL database from an AWS EC2 instance running amazon linux.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
db=_mysql.connect(host="hostname",user="dbuser",passwd="dbpassword",db="database")
db.query("""SELECT id, field1 FROM test""")
r=db.store_result()
row = r.fetch_row()
print row
```

I have installed the python module with pip:

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

When I run the script I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

When I research this I keep on digging up a lot of solutions for Ubuntu/Debian linux that don't work for amazon linux.

How can I fix this error on amazon linux and run the script?

Also, from any experienced linux users observing/answering: Is there any advantage to using amazon linux as I try to learn more linux and pick up AWS or would I be better off using an Ubuntu/Debian image? I'm not an experienced linux user as probably shows from the question.

**Update**

I've realised that the installation of the package was unsuccessful on the amazon linux server. Here's the full output when I try to run the install via pip:

```
$ sudo pip install MySQL-Python
Collecting MySQL-Python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-Python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-Python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-B1IkvH/MySQL-Python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RNgtpa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql55 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-B1IkvH/MySQL-Python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RNgtpa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-B1IkvH/MySQL-Python/
```

Comment: I would check modules installed on the installation of python, which you are running at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - yes the module doesn't appear to have been successfully installed. Output from pip install now pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

Only a workaround, but one that worked for me in situations where I could not easily call "sudo pip install".

What you (often, not always) can do:

1. Turn to a system where that python module you are looking for works
2. Identify its "location", for example, after installing enum34 on my ubuntu, the installation would put files under */usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum*
3. Put that directory in an archive
4. On your "target" system, extract that archive locally
5. Manipulate the python path to include the locally extracted archive

As said, this isn't beautiful; but if no better answers come in; you have at least something to try ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So in a nutshell this is dumping the already installed code in another system into the new system and amending the path as necessary. Isn't the installation process any more complicated than this though? Aren't there things that could get missed?

Any experience with AWS? Would you bother with amazon linux?

Comment: Correct; dump and amend ;-) Well, for some python modules, the install process might even include compiling stuff. My point is basically: this helped me in the past. I dont have experience with AWS; and I can't tell you if you have to bother with Amazon Linux!

Comment: Cheers. I think on reflection I will continue to learn on Ubuntu. After some more reading I think amazon linux would come into it's own when amazon staff are supporting large setups, not necessary for me to learn AWS/linux with.

Comment: Well, one can always look at such "decisions" (where should I "invest" my learning time) using a "business perspective". To a certain degree it is always valid to ask "what will be the 'return on investment' if I spent my time here .. or there".